# Mysql query to find records that are common in multiple columns across multiple tables.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table1

```
- | a  | b  | C  | d  | e  |
- |----+----+----+----+----|
- | 1  | 2  | 3  | 2  | 9  |
- | 2  | 3  | 2  | 3  | 5  |
- | 3  | 8  | 4  | 4  | 2  |  
- | 4  | 9  | 8  | 5  | 3  | 
- | 5  | 1  | 9  | 7  | 1  |   
- | 6  | 12 | 10 | 9  | 10 |
```

Table2

```
- | a2 | b2 | C2 | d2 | e2 |
- |----+----+----+----+----|
- | 1  | 2  | 3  | 2  | 9  |
- | 2  | 3  | 2  | 3  | 5  |
- | 3  | 8  | 4  | 4  | 2  |  
- | 4  | 9  | 8  | 5  | 3  | 
- | 5  | 1  | 9  | 7  | 1  |   
- | 6  | 12 | 10 | 9  | 10 |
```

Results i want:

2,3

Because 2 and 3 are common in all the columns across these two tables.

I have tried :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.a FROM  `table1` c1 
JOIN  `table1` c2 ON ( c1.a = c2.b )  
JOIN  `table1` c3 ON ( c2.b = c3.c )  
JOIN  `table1` c4 ON ( c3.c = c4.d )  
JOIN  `table1` c5 ON ( c4.d = c5.e )
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

It works good for table1 but how to join more tables.

Comment: Waiting for reply ...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a relational database problem at all. How are 2 and 3 the returned values when you have some rows which don't contain either value?  It is not really clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @MikeBrant : Please recheck, All the columns have 2 and 3.

Comment: one question, what are your specifications? May be more than a number repeated in each row, or only one of them will be repeated?

Comment: @Chococroc: Yes, a number could be repeated in same row and same column. But  i want all the numbers present in all the columns.

Comment: @TarunBhardwaj The number may be repeated in each column, but in mysqlm you are viewing data at a row level.  Again, I don't think this is a relational database problem, but more of a matrix problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.a FROM  `t1` c1 
JOIN  `t1` c2 ON ( c1.a = c2.b )  
JOIN  `t1` c3 ON ( c2.b = c3.c )  
JOIN  `t1` c4 ON ( c3.c = c4.d )  

JOIN  `t2` c5 ON ( c4.d = c5.a )  
JOIN  `t2` c6 ON ( c5.b = c6.c )  
JOIN  `t2` c7 ON ( c6.c = c7.d )  
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ade/6

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start with this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa0832/1) with 10 rows.

Where you will count it to equal how many rows you are comparing.
Your example has table1 6 rows, table2 6 rows.
12 rows for example is...

```
SELECT
    a.value,
    COUNT(a.value) as count
FROM 
(
    SELECT a AS value
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b AS value
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C AS value
    FROM table1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d AS value
    FROM table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e AS value
    FROM table1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a2 AS value
    FROM table2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b2 AS value
    FROM table2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C2 AS value
    FROM table2     

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d2 AS value
    FROM table2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e2 AS value
    FROM table2


) a
GROUP BY value
HAVING count >= 12
ORDER BY count DESC
```

to be more dynamic on the row count you can also try:

```
HAVING count >= ((SELECT COUNT(*) as t1 FROM table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) as t2 FROM table2))
```

---

**update**

Something similar to your approach is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d52/4

```
SELECT t.value, COUNT(t.value) as count
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT c1.a AS value FROM  `table1` c1 
JOIN  `table1` c2 ON ( c1.a = c2.b )  
JOIN  `table1` c3 ON ( c2.b = c3.c )  
JOIN  `table1` c4 ON ( c3.c = c4.d )  
JOIN  `table1` c5 ON ( c4.d = c5.e )

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT c1.a2 AS value FROM  `table2` c1 
JOIN  `table2` c2 ON ( c1.a2 = c2.b2 )  
JOIN  `table2` c3 ON ( c2.b2 = c3.C2 )  
JOIN  `table2` c4 ON ( c3.C2 = c4.d2 )  
JOIN  `table2` c5 ON ( c4.d2 = c5.e2 )
) t
GROUP BY t.value
HAVING count = 2
```

Comment: Its Working!!... But, Suppose i delete 2 from `table1` `a` and i add 2 to `table1` `b`. now there are total 12 2s so it will be on the top. I want data that is present in all the columns.